# Acer Aspire V7 - Power Button and Lid Closed

Tags: laptop, power

I want to use my laptop with the lid closed with external screen, keyboard and mouse.  I would like to turn on or take out of sleep/hibernation but the machine not allow this as long as the lid is shut.

Is there any was of configuring this or am I out to lunch here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Windows follow the below steps:

> Open Power Options by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start
>   button, clicking Control Panel, clicking System and Security, and then
>   clicking Power Options.
>
> On the Select a power plan page, click Change plan settings for the
>   plan that you want to change.
>
> On the Change settings for the plan page, click Change advanced power
>   settings.
>
> On the Advanced settings tab, expand Power buttons and lid, expand Lid
>   close action, choose what you want your laptop to do when you close
>   the lid, both for when it's running on battery and when it's plugged
>   in, and then click OK.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/change-what-happens-when-you-close-your-laptop

That will allow you to set the laptop to stay awake when the lid is closed.

For disabling sleep/hibernate read the below link or specify how you would like it to be set in light of this guide: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/819-hibernate-enable-disable.html

There are important decisions (does it behave differently when plugged in vs not plugged in, etc.) which you will need to decide.

Comment: Thanks, So far so good...  I have the lid closed and sleep/hibernate do not kick in.  This is good!  Now if I want to hibernate without opening the lid I can do from the shut down options... but I can not get out of hibernate without opening the lid.  Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: I've run in to some model-based inconsistencies pertaining to that. If your laptop has an external power button you might be able to change the 'power button action' and/or 'sleep button action' settings (should be under the "Power buttons and lid" section where you changed the lid close actions) to do 'hibernate' which should toggle to wake up. If this answered your question mark it as the 'answer' and let me know if you have any further issues! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's possible - this model is specifically designed to do just that: deactivate power button while lid is shut.
I have no idea if it's software or hardware solution, but it's definitely there.